# Using partials within function as value on a map

Tags: clojure

Firstly; sorry if the terminology I'm using is incorrect, I'm still very new to clojure and the paradigm shift is taking some time.

I am trying to work with a function which takes the first item from a set which is greater than twelve (is a 'teen' number). I can write this when I'm just applying it directly to a set, but I'm unsure how to write the function within a map. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried a few things, typically along the lines of `(partial (first (filter (partial < 12))))` but without any luck at all so far, and researching definitions of filter/partial has not yet proved fruitful.

**TL/DR**
I want to have, as a value in a map, a function which takes the first item in a list which is greater than 12.

```clj
(def test-set [1, 8, 15, 22, 29])

(def some-functions {
  :first first
  :last last
  :teenth "I don't know what to put here"
})


(first (filter (partial < 12) test-set))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an anonymous function when defining the map (https://riptutorial.com/clojure/example/15544/defining-anonymous-functions)

```
> (def some-functions {
  :first first
  :last last
  :teenth #(first (filter (partial < 12) %))})

> ((:first some-functions) test-set)
1

> ((:last some-functions) test-set)
29

> ((:teenth some-functions) test-set)
15
```

Of course you could also have explicitly defined your function and used it in your map:

```
> (defn teenth [coll] (first (filter (partial < 12) coll)))

> (def some-functions {
  :first first
  :last last
  :teenth teenth})
```

(As an aside, be careful with the word `set`. In clojure sets are unordered collections of unique values. https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures)

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful answer; particularly the link to the tutorial, and the note about using `set`; I'm keen to get to grips with the terminology so that kind of pointer is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I found a small improvement to @jas' answer.

The functions

```
#(first (filter (partial < 12) %))
```

and

```
(defn teenth [coll] (first (filter (partial < 12) coll)))
```

use a combination of `first` and `filter`.

This is a use case for the `some` function as stated on clojuredocs.org [1].

I would propose to refactor the functions to

```
(fn [coll] (some #(if (< 12 %) %) coll))
```

and

```
(defn teenth [coll] (some #(if (< 12 %) %) coll))
```

Due to the slightly more complex predicate function `#(if (< 12 %) %)` we cannot use `partial` anymore.

Please be aware that you cannot create nested anonymous functions by using the reader macro `#()` [2]. In this case, you have to use `fn` to create the nested anonymous function as shown above.

Actually, you could use `fn` twice, but in my opinion it's not readable anymore:

```
(fn [coll] (some (fn [e] (if (< 12 e) e)) coll))
```

[1] https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some#example-542692c6c026201cdc326940

[2] https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, many thanks for the additional input!